# How can i change the output of the Gradio framework?

Tags: stable-diffusion, gardio

Stable Diffusion WebUI uses the Gradio framework to render the UI to the client. There is an input control labeled "Batch count" that is set to the maximum of 100. I would like to change it to 200. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is you can modify "Batch Count" parameters in the file called `ui-config.json` and then restart it.